# attached email sending in php 5.2.11

Tags: php, email, send

I have a problem with sending email with attachment.

It is working on server which has php 5.2.8 installed while it's not working on the other sever which has php 5.2.11 installed.
Following is the function

```
function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message) 
{
    $file = $path.$filename;
    $file_size = filesize($file);
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $name = basename($file);
    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use diff. tyoes here 
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."--";
    if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
       echo  "Picture Uploaded Successfully... OK"; // or use booleans here
  return true;
    } else {
        echo  "mail send ... ERROR!";
return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do some basic debugging to find out what the problem is, it's impossible to give any useful feedback with just a wall of code

Comment: I tried your function on my system. I get this error: `Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP"** and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\LearnPHP\index.php on line 38 mail send ... ERROR!` *What error do you get?*

Answer (score 0):

Use a mail library, like [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/).

Comment: Picture Uploaded Successfully... OK Thsi the output given by the mail function. It does not give any error. But the mail is not sending